# NHibernate GroupBy, aggregate on relation collection with select

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I use NHibernate 4.0.0.4000 with linq provider and I try to write such query:

```
var jsonResult = queryable
                .GroupBy(boughtInfo => new {boughtInfo.SoldByAdministrator.UserName})
                .Select(group => new object[]
                {
                   group.Key,
                   group.Count(),
                   group.Sum(x => x.Payments.Count),
                   group.Sum(x => x.Payments.Sum(payment => payment.PaymentValue))
               })
               .Skip(itemsToSkipCount)
               .Take(itemsToTake)
               .ToList();
```

However I get `HibernateException`

- Additional information: Query Source could not be identified:
  ItemName = payment, ItemType = ...BoughtServicePayment, Expression =
  from BoughtServicePayment payment in [x].Payments

Group values is collection of type: `BoughtServiceInformation` which contain `ICollection<BoughtServicePayment> Payments` (mapped with `HasMany` at `BoughtServiceInformation`). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you simplify your query and check if it works. Remove all stuff in the Select but group.Key.UserName. Then add line by line again till you find the line that is causing trouble.

Comment: the problem is caused by summing on x => x.Payments but how to fix that and why this doesn't work? Normally I'd GroupBy UserName, Skip, Take, then deffer query with ToList() and select appropraite data - but with pure GroupBy and Skip,Take I get exception that some columns weren't selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the grouping you can do it like this:

```
ISessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.CreateSessionFactory();
        ISession session = factory.OpenSession();

        var res = session.Query<Client>()
            .Select(
                x => new object[]{
                    x.Transactions.Count(),
                    x.Transactions.Sum( y => y.SomeAmount),
                }
            )
            .ToList();
```

The root would by Aministrator (SoldByAdministrator). You can even use Where clauses like x.Transactions.Where(y => y.DSFS == 32424).Count().

The generated sql will contain subqueries, which is ok in my oppinion.

If you are not happy with performace, then you can still user QueryOver, which is much closer to DB operations than LINQ.